# Do we assume the policy to be deterministic when proving the optimality?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, policies, deterministic-policy

In reinforcement learning, when we talk about the principle of optimality, do we assume the policy to be deterministic?

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify what your question is? Is it "when we talk about the principle of optimality, do we assume policy to be deterministic?"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Which "principle of optimality" are you talking about exactly? Where did you read this term? Maybe provide a reference to the book? Are you talking about the optimality of the _value iteration_ and/or _policy iteration_? I heard the term "principle of optimality" only in the context of dynamic programming algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading Sutton-Barto, Introduction to Reinforcement learning. I'm asking in the context of DP only.